# .htacess redirect from one url on one domain to a different url on a DIFFERENT domain

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect from domainA.com/page to domainB.com/pageX These are two different domains, two different pages or urls.

Note that Redirect 301 /page domainB.com/pageX works but then every other page on domainA.com breaks with a 404 error.

Answer (score 4):

From .htaccess files:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /page http://domainB.com/pageX
```

Comment: You need to state that as an option to allow `RewriteEngine On`. If it worked could you mark it as the accepted answer, thanks! :)